# How to hides the keyboard when we use the UITextView?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that i use the textview.But when we click on textview,or completion of entering the text into textview,textview delegate methods are not fired.Ias writtent he textview.delegate=self also.But they are not firing.So pleas etell me how to solve this one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dismiss+keyboard+iphone

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextViewDelegate` methods do not handle dismissal of the keyboard: you must do that yourself, by calling:

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

This will then trigger the `textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView` delegate method. What you need to do is call the `resignFirstResponder` method in response to whatever actions you require - if this is tapping outside the text view you'll need to create a gesture recognizer / button  / whatever to pick up that tap and call `resignFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Keyboard notifications like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) 
    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

and in `-(void) keyboardWillShow {}` set `[myTextField resignFirstResponder];`

hope this helps.